# xml authoring , dita web based editor

Tags: dita

I'm looking for web based dita(topic,concept,reference,ditamap) editor.

Example site : [xopus](http://www.xopus.com/demo/simple)

Early I used the same editor for creating xml files and converting them into doc,docx,pdf etc.

But Now I got requirement to generate dita complaint xml files.

I don't want to go for oxygen applet based web editor.But outside oxygen(30 days free trail version) standalone application is able to achieves my requirement which  can't be embed in to web application .

I'm looking is there any web based dita editing tools ??

Comment: I found easyDITA some weeks ago, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I'm looking something which is free of cost

Comment: This is about the only free DITA aware editor I know of. It's outdated however. http://sourceforge.net/projects/sernafree.mirror/ For what it's worth, Oxygen is an awesome tool.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you couldn't use the Oxygen applet version, other than not being free (which I doubt you will find anyway) I'd say that's the best way to go.

Comment: Nowadays applet tags are getting deprecating in html5 we don't have applet tag . :( .

Comment: @Suryaprakash Pisay you can still use a embed tag instead of applet? See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#the-applet-element

Comment: @Fox32 , Yes we can do that way . But the thing is I don't to go for it.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is that finding a free XML editor that's robust is difficult now. If you cannot use any of the commercial applications, then you will wind up having to use something like JEdit but that won't meet your need of using a web-based editor.

I doubt you can find anything to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, xmlmind personal editors (DITA, DocBook, xml, xhtml) are free to use for a personal use.
http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/dita_editor.html

Comment: It is better to add the question here itself rather than adding a link to it. Links may change (or return 404) in future and that will make this question totally useless for future visitors.